# How to find value "Branched from" with Crucible REST API?

Tags: git, rest, atlassian-crucible, eyeql

Is a way to get the same value which is shown in Crucible "details" page of a review as "Branched from" value? It's branch from which was cloned branch of the review (Git). How to find it with REST API? I see only these [docs](https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/crucible.html) and [this](https://docs.atlassian.com/fisheye-crucible/latest/wadl/fisheye.html) and can't find needed API call. I suspected it can be "rest-service-fe/revisionData-v1/revisionInfo/" call, but it returns 404 all the time... And I'm not sure that it is needed call even, because no any "branches" in its response actually.

Answer (score 1):

it's the API was never marked as public one therefore it's not listed on the pages you've pointed, however it has never changed and I don't think it ever will.

You can get list of tracked branches for a review by using this URL:

`FISHEYE_URL/rest/branchreview/latest/trackedbranch/$REVIEW_ID`

You'll get a JSON list of tracked branches and the fields you're after are:

- reviewedBranch
- baseBranch

> It's branch from which was cloned branch of the review (Git)

Note that branches in Git are not clones one of another. Those are basically pointers to a commit. Fisheye&Crucible will show you the diff between *reviewedBranch* (and being more specific *lastChangesetId*) the  and *baseBranch*.